# Duplicate Record Created Using PHP Services

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Under what circumstances will the following line create two records instead of one?

The line only runs once, I traced the program to make sure.

```
createIndcsfResult.token = indcsfService.createIndcsf(indCSF2);
```

Standard Service

```
/**
 * Returns the item corresponding to the value specified for the primary key.
 *
 * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
 *
 * 
 * @return stdClass
 */
public function createIndcsf($item) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (indcsf_name, indcsf_yourcsf_id, indcsf_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sis', $item->indcsf_name, $item->indcsf_yourcsf_id, $item->indcsf_status);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $autoid;
}
```

Comment: We don't know how your Service works unless you share a biiiit more than just that line.

Comment: I cant post the whole thing, it runs over many many lines, just want to know what would cause it.

Comment: Your Service is for some reason creating two records on one createIndcsf call. Unless we can see what your Service does, we have no idea why the service is doing it.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your client (flex) is calling the service twice.